# How to set up Ubuntu Server as a wireless + ethernet router with IPv4 and IPv6

Tags: networking, dhcp, intel-wireless, ipv6, wireless-access-point

I have a computer running Ubuntu Server (14.04 but I want to upgrade to 16.04 when it becomes available) with two Ethernet interfaces and one WiFi interface.

The interfaces are:

- Ethernet towards WAN: `p2p1`
- Ethernet towards LAN: `eth0`
- WiFi towards LAN: `wlan0` (Intel Corporation Wireless 7260, driver: `iwlwifi`)

I'd like to do the following:

- Set up `wlan0` in the access point mode with WPA2 encryption in the 802.11 b/g/n mode. (I don't mind enabling 802.11a, too, but I don't need it. I need 802.11n and b/g legacy.)
- Bridge `wlan0` and `eth0` together as `br0`.
- Use DHCP to configure an IPv4 address for `p2p1`.
- Set up a DHCP server to assign private IPv4 addresses to hosts connected to `br0`.
- Set up NAT between `br0` and `p2p1` for IPv4 traffic.
- Use DHCPv6 to fetch an IPv6 prefix for `p2p1`.
- Set up router advertisement to assign IPv6 addresses under the prefix to hosts connected to `br0`.
- Route IPv6 traffic between `p2p1` and `br0`.
- Set up a caching DNS server and advertise it as the DNS server to hosts on `br0` (but block queries from `p2p1`).
- Set up firewall rules that block all CIFS/SMB, possibily other insecure Windows traffic and CUPS printing between the `br0` LAN and the `p2p1` WAN.
- Set up whatever other firewall rules are considered best practice while not preventing efficient Skype, WebRTC and push notification traffic between WAN and the hosts on the `br0` network.

This should be a basic "turn an Ubuntu box into an IPv4+IPv6 home router" kind of thing. I've done a lot of searching already, but I've failed to find a guide that matches my needs. In particular, I have trouble finding guidance for setting up `iwlwifi`-based `wlan0` with WPA2 in the AP mode and then using that as part of a brige interface. (I found guides that talk about WEP or of using `wlan0` as the WAN interface that connects to an AP as a client or explicitly using Atheros drivers as opposed to `iwlwifi`.) Also, I have trouble finding guidance for the IPv6 part. Superficially, it looks like some combination of `bridge-utils`, `hostapd` and `dnsmasq` could address all of the above. Maybe.

Any pointers to a guide that already covers this or other advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The significant bit was locating a [tutorial for fetching the IPv6 prefix](https://hveem.no/using-dnsmasq-for-dhcpv6).

Other than that, the comments in the default config files and the obviously-discoverable tutorials for `bridge-utils`, `hostapd` and `dnsmasq` worked.

With `ufw` the key thing was to use the `route` keyword in rules that apply to traffic that doesn't terminate on the router computer itself.

(I used AppArmor to confine `wide-dhcpv6-client`, `dnsmasq` and `hostapd` by following the [guidance for `aa-logprof` on the community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor).)